# Stripe API | Payment Links | Need to create a payment link with on runtime price

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I need to create a stripe payment link to send to a customer. The price would be set on runtime and it's a service so parse there is no product.
My ultimate solution would be if i can simply do something along like so

PaymentLink.price = 100 USD (setting up price directly in link instead of creating a product/price model)

Create payment link

Get link

Tried following the below documentation but it includes setting up a product and price model
https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/api

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you need to programmatically set a different `amount` for each session it's much better to start using [Stripe Checkout Sessions](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout), instead of Payment Links. They are much more powerful and customisable. You will generate a fresh Session with a specific customer and redirect them to the payment page immediately.

Now, to set the `amount` in Checkout Sessions dynamically, you will need to make use of `price_data` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data). It lets you create a Price on the fly, just for this specific Session. You can pre-create a Product and re-use its ID every time for `price_data.product` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-product). It will just set the image and name/description for your Checkout Session.